# Webpage contents are misaligned and float to the top left automatically. How do I align my elements correctly?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the noob source code, I have lots to learn and to polish. Whenever I use `float: left/right`, it aligns correctly. If I remove the floats in each div/element, all my images and everything gets bunched up in the top left of my container for some reason.

WEBPAGE: http://eveo.org/scd/site/

**CSS:**

```
body { background: #e9e6e3 url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/bg.png') no-repeat center top; 
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0; }

#content { width: 960px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto; }

# header { height: 76px; width: 960px; }

    .logo { 
        background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/logo.png'); 
        width: 276px; 
        height: 76px; 
        float: left; 
        } 

    .ad { 
        background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/ad.png'); 
        width: 641px; 
        height: 76px;
        float: right; 
        } 

# nav_search { 
    height: 98px; 
    width: 960px; 
    }

    .navbar { 
        width: 729px; 
        height: 38px; 
        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left bottom,
            left top,
            color-stop(0.29, rgb(0,0,0)),
            color-stop(0.88, rgb(88,88,90))
            );
        background-image: 
            -moz-linear-gradient(
            center bottom,
            rgb(0,0,0) 29%,
            rgb(88,88,90) 88%
            );
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        margin: 30px 0 30px 0; 
        float: left; 
        }

    .search { 
        background: #FFFFFF;
        width: 214px;
        height: 36px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
             border-radius: 3px;
             -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
             -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
             box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
         float: right; 
         margin: 30px 0 30px 0; 
         border: 1px solid #b9b9b9; 
         }

#news_stream { 
    background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/news_bg.png');
    width: 960px; 
    height: 232px;
    float:right; 
    }

#events {
    background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/events.png');
    height: 51px;
    width: 960px;   
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0; 
    float: left; 
    }

/* panels */

#panels { 
    height: 156px; 
    width: 960px; 
    }

    #panels .community { 
        background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/panel/community.png');
        height: 156px;
        width: 342px;
        float: left; 
        }

    #panels .team_roster { 
        background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/panel/team_roster.png');
        height: 156px;
        width: 282px;
        float: left; 
        }

    #panels .tournaments { 
        background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/panel/tournaments.png');
        height: 156px;
        width: 312px;
        float:right;
        }
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 

<head>

    <title>StarCraftDream.com - Team SCD</title> 
    <!-- STYLESHEETS: grid_layout, stylesheet, fonts, slide, shadowbox --> 
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

</head> 

    <body>
    <!-- spacing purposes â€¢ will remove later, noob code FTL -->
        <br /><br /><br />
    <!-- spacing purposes -->

        <div id="content">

            <div id="header">
                <div class="logo"></div>
                <div class="ad"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="nav_search">
                <div class="navbar"></div>
                <div class="search"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="news_stream">
            </div>

            <div id="events">
            </div>

            <div id="panels">
                <div class="community"></div>
                <div class="team_roster"></div>
                <div class="tournaments"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but if you haven't already, install FireBug in firefox and use it to enable and disable different styles on your page. It is a good way to get a good feedback loop on what works and what doesn't while you are learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day dear sir! Floating elements is a delicate matter and it is important you know how it works as well as when an element is 'in-flow' or 'out of flow'. Not knowing what the difference is will create unexpected results.

As a baseline try to float as little as possible as it can get confusing fast. Luckily your layout isn't exactly complicated (looks nice though!).

What you want to do to force normal elements to appear after element you floated is clear them. You can do this by adding the attribute clear: [left|right|both] which clears left floated items, right floated items or both respectively on the element which needs to clear the floated items... I modified your layout so only the nessacery elements are floated and the rest is kept in flow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 

<head>

    <title>StarCraftDream.com - Team SCD</title> 
    <!-- STYLESHEETS: grid_layout, stylesheet, fonts, slide, shadowbox --> 
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

</head> 

    <body>

        <div id="content">

            <div id="header">
                <div class="logo"></div>
                <div class="ad"></div>

                <div class="clearl"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="nav_search">
                <div class="search"></div>
                <div class="navbar"></div>

                <div class="clearr"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="news_stream">
            </div>

            <div id="events">
            </div>

            <div id="panels">
                <div class="community"></div>
                <div class="team_roster"></div>
                <div class="tournaments"></div>

                <div class="clearl"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

As for the css that goes with that:

```
body { 
    background: #e9e6e3 url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/bg.png') no-repeat center top; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll; /* IE adds a scrollbar by default, this forces the rest of the browsers to add one too even if no scrolling is required */
}

#content { 
    width: 960px; 
    /*height: 500px; Why set a height when you can let elements expand this block as they which? */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0; /* content now has whitespace in the top and bottom */
}

#header { 
    /* We don't need to set styles here ;) */
}

    .logo { 
        background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/logo.png'); 
        width: 276px; 
        height: 76px;
        float: left;
    }

    .ad { 
        background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/ad.png'); 
        width: 641px; 
        height: 76px;
        float: right;
     }

#nav_search { 
    padding: 30px 0;
}

    .navbar { 
        width: 729px; 
        height: 38px; 

        background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left bottom,
            left top,
            color-stop(0.29, rgb(0,0,0)),
            color-stop(0.88, rgb(88,88,90))
        );

        background-image: 
            -moz-linear-gradient(
            center bottom,
            rgb(0,0,0) 29%,
            rgb(88,88,90) 88%

        );

        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .search { 
        background: #FFFFFF;
        width: 214px;
        height: 36px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
             border-radius: 3px;
             -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
             -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
             box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
         float: right; 
         border: 1px solid #b9b9b9; 
    }

#news_stream { 
    background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/news_bg.png'); 
    height: 232px;
}

#events {
    background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/events.png');
    height: 51px;  
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0; 
}

/* panels */

#panels { 
    /* We don't need to set styles here ;) */
}

    #panels .community { 
        background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/panel/community.png');
        height: 156px;
        width: 342px;
        float: left; 
    }

    #panels .team_roster { 
        background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/panel/team_roster.png');
        height: 156px;
        width: 282px;
        float: left; 
    }

    #panels .tournaments { 
        background: url('http://eveo.org/scd/site/images/panel/tournaments.png');
        height: 156px;
        width: 312px;
        float:right;
    }


.clearl {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: left;
}

.clearr {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: right; /* You'll notice I added some extra styles here, this is to make sure IE doesn't force the extra block element to have any sort of layout and messing things up in the process */
}
```